# Why is the valuation of a separable closure equal to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

I am reading a paper by Serre, in which at some point he say

> We extend the valuation $v$ from $K$ to $K^{sep}$; in this way we obtain a valuation on $K^{sep}$ with value group $v(K^{sep \times})=\mathbb{Q}$.

Here, $K$ is a number field complete with respect to $v$ a discrete valuation, and $K^{sep}$ is $K$'s separable closure. A separable closure is essentially the maximal Galois extension, or equivalently contains all separable elements in the algebraic closure of $K$. I am not entirely sure why that would yield $v(K^{sep \times})=\mathbb{Q}$? Like it could miss some elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, so I am not sure why it is exactly $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: ...Ahhh, you have a **number** field, so $\text{char } K = 0$. But then the algebraic closure coincides with the separable closure; why did you write about the latter?

Comment: The paper is Serre's 1972 ”Les propri´et´es galoisiennes des points des torsions des courbes elliptiques". A translation can be found here: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57bf2a6de3df281593b7f57d/t/600db4f1676f6519410f71e9/1611511026377/serre_1972_translation.pdf. Please see Section 1.8.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Char $K=0$ does not imply the algebraic closure is same as the separable closure? For example $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ has characteristic $0$. As far as I am aware, the algebraic closure is equal to the separable closure iff the field is perfect.

Comment: Every field of characteristic 0 is perfect though. $\Bbb R$ is not algebraic over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ or $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Oops, yes. But my question still remains. If in this case the algebraic closure is same as the separable closure, would that not imply that $v(K^{sep \times})=\mathbb{R}$ in fact? I still do not know why it is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Let $\pi$ be the uniformizer of $K$, $v(\pi) = 1$, and the valuation be extended from $K$ to a field $L$. Then for any algebraic element $\alpha \in L/K$, [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618149) $v(\alpha) \in \Bbb Q$.
The only thing that remains is to prove the existence of a degree-$p$ irreducible separable polynomial in $K$ in case $K$ is not perfect. I suspect this to be a consequence of Artin-Schreier theory (no expertise there).

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist This is helpful, thank you so much!